# How to grab screenshot name

Tags: c#, .net, selenium

I have class that takes screenshot of the page and saves image date and time format that way I have unique screenshot. But I can not figure it out how can call this method outside of class to take screenshot and grab the name to print on my console. This is my Utility class I perform screenshot:

```
public class Utility
{        
    public static void TakeScreenshot()
    {
        String now = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyy hh-mm tt ");
        try
        {
            Screenshot ss = ((ITakesScreenshot)Driver.Instance).GetScreenshot();
            ss.SaveAsFile(@".\Screenshots\"+now+"Screenshot.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I can call my screenshot class here in this method but how can I get new created screenshot name?

```
[Test]
public void ScreenshotTest()
{
    Utility.TakeScreenshot(); //Here I can perform screenshot but how can I grab screenshot name
    Console.Write("");        // So I can print here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your method instead to return void, to return string and then return the name of your just taken screenshot

```
  string ssName= now+"Screenshot.png";
            Screenshot ss = ((ITakesScreenshot)Driver.Instance).GetScreenshot();
            ss.SaveAsFile(@".\Screenshots\"+now+"Screenshot.png",  System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

at the end of your method use the `return ssName;`
and that will allow you to get the name as a return from your method

```
String ssName= Utility.TakeScreenshot(); 
    Console.Write("ssName");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is same as Csharls's answer. Just explained..

Utility Class

```
public class Utility
{
    public static string TakeScreenshot()
    {
        String now = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyy hh-mm tt ");
        string FileName = now + "Screenshot.png";
        try
        {
            Screenshot ss = ((ITakesScreenshot)Driver.Instance).GetScreenshot();
            ss.SaveAsFile(@".\Screenshots\" + FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            throw;
        }
        return FileName;
    }
}
```

Call Location

```
[Test]
    public void ScreenshotTest()
    {
        string FileName;
        FileName = Utility.TakeScreenshot(); //Here I can perform screenshot but how can I grab screenshot name
        Console.Write(FileName);        // So I can print here
    }
```